# How to instantiate C++ member string reference

Tags: c++, string, reference, instantiation

I have a class with a `std::string&` as a member of that class. I want to instantiate that reference, but I don't have anything to instantiate it to until a bit later.

How can I instantiate the `std::string&` member?

```c
#include <string>
class Temp {
    public : 
        Temp(): _line("") {}
    private:
        std::string& _line;

}
```

Comment: In short, you can't. A reference has to be set in the constructor. Maybe use a pointer? Or just a copy.

Comment: Why do you need the reference? why not just have the string?

Comment: @BoBTFish Thanks. I was afraid that was the answer. Good to know. So it seems that there is no way to have a reference member function unless I pass a value as arguments to the constructor, right?

Comment: why don't you just use a setter where `std::string _line` and `void set(std::string &line) { _line = line; }`?

Comment: @Mgetz One of the things I love about SO is that so many make me think harder about my problem and thus improve my implementation. Thanks!

Comment: @stellarossa Better yet, with a `const` reference in the argument.

Comment: @H2CO3 i like to live dangerously

Comment: @Jeremy if you *really* need a reference (and I have serious doubts you do), provide two constructors, one that takes a ref and sets it, the other that takes nothing and sets the reference to a class-static default. That said, *seriously* question whether this is required, because the places where it would be are rare.

Comment: @Jeremy someone has to ask the obvious question, because sometimes the obvious answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a reference as member in a class mean that you are using the same pointed data from the begining to the end.

If you need to init it during the lifetime of the class it is not possible. As soon as you put a ref, you have to handle copy and assignement yourself. Are you sure this is really what you want ?

You need either a pointer if you want to point to another `std::string` that will be given to you later or a `std::string` where you will store the value you want.

But please avoid the only thing that would allow you to init a ref when you have nothing passed in the constructor:

```
Temp(): _line(*(new std::string)) {} // NEVER EVER !
```

Comment: you are right that I need to consider if a reference is what I really need to do. Probably don't need to , but this is how you would do if you did need to.